# PhantomJS 2.1.1 ERROR: SyntaxError: Functions cannot be declared in a nested block in strict mode

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, karma-mocha, karma-webpack

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Functions cannot be declared in a nested block in strict mode
  at :/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/_karma_webpack_149363/commons.js:58529:0
```

Does anyone know where I could start trying to figure out this error?
It appeared after I upgraded `@progress/kendo-react-buttons` to version 4.6.0

I'm not sure where strict mode is set, but it might be in package.json: `"engine-strict": true,`
But it might not be a good idea to set that to false.